# gdbserver locking up when trying to step through code

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb, gdbserver

When sending the `step` command from my host machine running gdb to my remote target (connected over TCP/IP) running the gdbserver, I receive the following error on the target

```
ptrace: Input/output error.
input_interrupt, count = 1 c = 36 ('$')
```

Nothing happens on the target after this - just hangs. On the host's gdb, the following is displayed

```
(gdb) step
warning: Remote failure reply: E01
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
```

This will continue indefinitely. Ends up with me having to reboot the target. `continue` works just fine and is able to trigger on my designated breakpoints. Could this fault be entirely on the gdbserver side or could it have something to do with my gdb configuration?

gdbserver version on the target

- GNU gdbserver (crosstool-NG linaro-1.13.1-4.9-2014.09 - Linaro GCC
  4.9-2014.09) 7.6.1-2013.10

gdb (built from source) version on the host

- GNU gdb (GDB) 7.7.1
- This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --target=arm-none-eabi".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the issue I was having was due to an incorrect target when compiling the host GDB. For the target processor I'm using, I needed to set the target flag to

`--target=arm-linux-gnueabihf`

So far, I'm able to step through my code as well as trigger on segfaults.